# Use of loops and switches in java

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, switch-statement

```
package labsheet1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ques5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int add, sub, mul, div;
        int onum;
        System.out.print("Enter first number :");
        num1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second number :");
        num2 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter operation number :");
        onum = input.nextInt();
        add = num1 + num2;
        sub = num1 - num2;
        mul = num1 * num2;
        div = num1 / num2;
        switch (onum) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Addition(+)");
                System.out.println("The result is " + add);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Subtraction(-)");
                System.out.println("The result is " + sub);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Multiplication(*)");
                System.out.println("The result is " + mul);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Division(/");
                System.out.println("The result is " + div);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("None of the operations");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my program. now I have to modify this by adding the following question at the end of the program: 
Do you want to make another calculation?

1. Yes
2. No

Enter your option:

If user selects yes (by entering 1), program will ask him again to enter two numbers. If no, program will exit.

I need to use a suitable loop for this. please help.

Comment: [The while and do-while Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: Calculate all results upfront may become a problem. Try "1" "0" "+" should result in 1. But will lead to division by zero error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

```
package labsheet1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ques5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num1;
        int num2;
        int add,sub,mul,div;
        int onum;
        String ans = "Yes";

        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter first number :");
            num1=input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter second number :");
            num2=input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter operation number :");
            onum=input.nextInt();

            add=num1+num2;
            sub=num1-num2;
            mul=num1*num2;
            div=num1/num2;

            switch(onum)
            {
               case 1:
                 System.out.println("Addition(+)");
                 System.out.println("The result is " +add);

                 break;
               case 2:
                  System.out.println("Subtraction(-)");
                  System.out.println("The result is " +sub);
                  break;
               case 3:
                  System.out.println("Multiplication(*)");
                  System.out.println("The result is " +mul);
                  break;
               case 4:
                  System.out.println("Division(/");
                  System.out.println("The result is " +div);
                  break;
               default:
                   System.out.println("None of the operations");
            }
            System.out.print("Do you want to make another calculation?");
            ans=input.nextLine();
         }while(ans.toLowerCase().equals("Yes"));
    }
```

}

Comment: it says The method nextString() is undefined for the type Scanner

Comment: Sorry, Missed the syntax. Usually I dont use Scanner class but only command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Do-while` loop the concept is simple: e.g.

```
String s;
       do{  
    InetAddress ip;
    try {
        System.out.println("Hello here");

    } catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        s = scan.next();
        }while(s.toUpperCase().equals("Y") ||
               s.toUpperCase().equals("YES"));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a hint how you can apply while loop for continue processing based on user input :-

```
static String userChoice;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Do you want to make another calculation (Y/N)\n");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        userChoice=input.nextLine();
        if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
        //Do your calculations
        }
        } else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            System.out.print("Program is exiting. No more calculations!!!");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.print("Enter a valid choice (Y/N) only !");
        }
```